Why is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ not high-dimensional enough?
In this paper [1], the authors consider the limiting distribution of $$S_{n,p}:=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$$ for $p\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, where $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ are centered iid $\mathbb R^p$-valued random variables. Here $p$ is a positive integer, possibly depending on $n$. They argue that there will be no limiting distribution of $S_n$ and write

Of course, we can think of $S_n$ as random elements in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (the countable product of $\mathbb R$), but weak convergence in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is equivalent to finite dimensional convergence, which is too weak a result to develop genuinely high-dimensional inference methods.

What do they mean? I understand that weak convergence (= convergence in distribution) in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is equivalent to weak convergence of the finite dimensional marginals. But I don't get why (or in what sense) $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is not high-dimensional enough.
The authors continue to consider sequences, so I doubt that taking the countable product is the issue here.
Edit: It seems to be that there is a misunderstanding on my part (see comments to the answer below). My thoughts are rooted in the following considerations:

If we let $p\rightarrow\infty$, we eventually have that $p = \infty$. In this case, we are in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$.

Let $\mathcal B$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ (endowed with the topology of point-wise convergence). In addition, let $\mu\pi_p$ denote the pushforward probability measure of some probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B$ under the coordinate projection $\pi_p$ mapping $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ into $\mathbb R^p$.

In the space of probability measures on $\mathcal B$, we consider the sequence $(P_n)_n$, where $P_n$ is the distribution of $$S_{n,\infty} :=\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\boldsymbol X_k$$ with $\boldsymbol X_1, \boldsymbol X_2,\dots, \boldsymbol X_n$ being centered iid $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$-valued random variables.

I can show that finite-dimensional weak convergence is equivalent to infinite-dimensional weak convergence in the sense that a sequence of probability measures $(P_n)_n$ on $\mathcal B$ converges weakly to a probability measure $P$ on $\mathcal B$ if and only if the sequence probability measures $(P_n\pi_p)_n$ converges weakly to the probability measure $P\pi_p$ for all $p\in\mathbb N$. This is Example 2.6 in [2].

In my case, $P_n\pi_p$ is the distribution of $S_{n,p}$ for any fixed $p\in\mathbb N$. I can show that $S_{n,p}$ converges weakly to $P\pi_p$, which is a $p$-variate normal distribution. Since finite-dimensional convergence is equivalent to infinite-dimensional convergence (in the above sense), I conclude from the convergence of $(P_n\pi_p)_n$ that $(P_n)_n$ converges weakly to $P$, and $P$ must be a Gaussian process as a Gaussian process is characterized by its finite-dimensional marginal distributions (which are multivariate normal distributions).

Conclusion:

I can model situations in which $p>n$ by considering $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$-valued random variables.
The distribution, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, of a sum of $n$ iid copies of such random variables scaled by $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$ can be assessed by employing known theory for weak convergence in finite-dimensional spaces.

That is, we have a model for $p>n$ situations with the (easy and known) theory from the finite-dimensional case. This sounds great to me, but apparently I am missing a key point here.


My question is now: why is this not sufficient? Or is there an error in my line of thinking, and if so, where? In other words, if I suggested the above model for $p\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, why wouldn't it be considered truly high-dimensional (as indicated by the quote)?
My initial thought was that $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ might be not high-dimensional enough in some sense, hence the question title. However, @Iosif Pinelis points out that $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is rather "'too high' dimensional for the finite-dimensional convergence to work." Why should the finite-dimensional convergence not work?

[1]  Victor Chernozhukov, Denis Chetverikov, Kengo Kato, and Yuta Koike (2023). High-Dimensional Data Bootstrap
[2] Patrick Billingsley (1969). Convergence of Probability Measures

The problem is not sequences / cardinality considerations - it's the topology on the space of random variables under consideration. I think the point here is that a sequence $S_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ equipped with the weak topology has a limit if and only if all $S_n$ lie in some $\mathbb{R}^N \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. To prove something resembling a CLT you need a topology in which allows convergence of sequences where the dimension gets arbitrarily large.

@PaulSiegel  Actually what you wrote is true in the dual space of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, i.e. the  space  $\mathbb R^\omega$ of  sequences with finite  support,  as inductive limit  $\bigcup_n\mathbb R^n$.  In the space  $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$  the weak topology  is the product topology and gives the point-wise convergence….

What is $p$? $\qquad$

$p$ is a positive integer, possibly depending on $n$.

The authors did not say anything like "$\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is not high-dimensional enough."
Rather, they said

"finite dimensional convergence [...] is too weak a result to develop genuinely high-dimensional inference methods".

The meaning here is rather the opposite: $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is "too high" dimensional for the finite-dimensional convergence to work. For instance, if you have a sequence $((Y_1(p))_{p\in\Bbb N},(Y_2(p))_{p\in\Bbb N},\dots)$ of stochastic processes of which you only know that the finite-dimensional distributions of the process $((Y_n(p))_{p\in\Bbb N}$ converge to the finite-dimensional distributions of some process $((Y_\infty(p))_{p\in\Bbb N}$ as ($n\to\infty$), you cannot in general conclude anything about convergence of the distributions of a functional of the entire path of the process $Y_n(\cdot)$ to the distribution of that functional of the entire path of the process $Y_\infty(\cdot)$. An example of such a functional is $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\ni y\mapsto\sup_{p\in\Bbb N}y(p)/a(p)$ for some positive function $a$ on $\Bbb N$.
So, if one wants to study the behavior of $S_{n,p}:=S_n$ for large $n$ and $p$, then it is not enough to know the behavior of $S_{n,p}$ for large $n$ but only for a fixed finite set of values $p$. You already "understand that weak convergence (= convergence in distribution) in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is equivalent to weak convergence of the finite dimensional marginals." So, the highlighted thesis follows.

On a somewhat positive note: In this comment, the OP wrote:

The fact that finite dimensional convergence implies infinite dimensional convergence sounds like a nice feature in that regard (as it simplifies things by a lot). In the paper, and in your answer, this fact sounds like I huge disadvantage though.

Of course, I said nothing of this sort. In fact, I did not talk about any advantages or disadvantages at all.
What can actually be said on this matter is the following. The convergence of  the finite-dimensional distributions is of course necessary for the convergence of the distributions of the entire processes. Moreover, there are a number of results saying that, with the additional tightness condition, the convergence of the finite-dimensional distributions is also sufficient for the convergence of the distribution of the entire processes -- see e.g. Theorems 7.1 and 13.1 in Billingsley.
Furthermore, the tightness condition cannot be dropped -- cf. Example 2.7 in Billingsley's book.
Yet more, according to Prokhorov's theorem, the tightness condition is necessary if the paths of the processes are in a Polish space.

But why is it not fruitful to study the behavior of $S_{n,p}$ for large $n$ and $p$ in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$? I may have a fundamental wrong perception, but I would expect that if I have convergence of $S_{n,p}$ for any finite $p$, then it follows that I  also have convergence of $S_{n,\infty}$ (to a Gaussian process). The fact that finite dimensional convergence implies infinite dimensional convergence sounds like a nice feature in that regard (as it simplifies things by a lot). In the paper, and in your answer, this fact sounds like I huge disadvantage though.

@Quertiopler : I hardly understand anything in your comment. (i) What do you mean, exactly, by "study the behavior of $S_{n,p}$ for large $n$ and $p$ in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$"? (ii) In what sense do you mean "convergence of $S_{n,p}$ for any finite $p$"? (iii) What is $S_{n,\infty}$, again exactly? (iv) What exactly do you mean by "finite dimensional convergence implies infinite dimensional convergence"?

I apologize for any confusion. I've added more information to my question. I would be grateful if you could review it again. Hopefully, my edits will clarify what I mean. Thank you very much!

@Quertiopler : Like your first comment under my answer, your edits are still incomprehensible to me, as a whole. In particular, I don't know in what sense "$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb R^p$ is identified as $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$" and why  "it is natural to assume that $P_n$ is the distribution of [...]", and what $P_n$ actually is.
Also, I see no clarification in the edits of your original, title question "Why is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ not high-dimensional enough?" In fact, I see nothing like a question in your edits.

I think my confusion is causing me to explain this poorly. I edited the question again. I've also added my motivation for the title (and why I didn't change it yet). You mention that "$\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is 'too high' dimensional for the finite-dimensional convergence to work.". How do you mean that? This could possibly resolve my confusion (at least partly) as I don't see why we should have any problems with finite-dimensional convergence to work in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Also, concerning your edit, I understand Example 2.7 in the book you link to to mean that tightness is not required.

@Quertiopler : (i) I have added details on '$\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is "too high" dimensional'. (ii) Your understanding of Example 2.7 in Billingsley is almost exactly opposite to its actual point, explicitly stated there: "Weak-convergence theory
in $C$ [and other spaces -- I.P.] goes beyond the finite-dimensional case in an essential way". That example actually shows that the tightness condition cannot be dropped. I have also added comments on the tightness to my answer.

Thanks for expanding. There was a small typo in my comment: Example 2.6 was meant. In fact, to my understanding Example 2.6 states that we can deduce convergence of a process from its finite-dimensional distributions, which would contradict the example you've added. I would say your example + Example 2.6 can be seen as  the root cause of my confusion.

@Quertiopler : The topology considered in that Example 2.6 (cf. Example 1.2 in Billingsley's book) is the one of pointwise convergence, which is of no use in almost any applications. For instance, the functional $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\ni y\mapsto\sup_{p\in\Bbb N}y(p)/a(p)$ in my answer is not continuous wrt the pointwise convergence, and hence the weak convergence of probability measures wrt to this topology will be of no consequence for this functional, as well as for integral-type and other functionals usually of interest.

Previous comment continued: In particular, the only linear functionals of the path $y$ that are continuous wrt that topology are the ones depending only on the values of $y$ on a finite set of time moments -- so that we are just back where we were, that is, back to finite-dimensional distributions.

Got it! So it's not the dimensionality of $\mathhb R^{\mathbb N}$ itself, but rather the topology considered. I will try to figure out whether the functionals that are of interest for me, will be continuous wrt that topology. Thank you very much for being so patient with me!

Often in mathematics, especially in applied mathematics, we have some finite object we care about, and we choose to study it by putting it in a sequence and studying the limit of the sequence, which is often easier to calculate with. The assumption that knowledge about the limit translates to useful knowledge about a fixed term in the sequence is heuristic, but it might be possible to make this rigorous.
To do this, one has to define a mathematical notion of what error is acceptable for a fixed term in the sequence, and check that the error arising from the approximation by the limit goes to $0$ as expected for the relevant notion of limit. But then one also has to check that the convergence to $0$ is fast enough (at least for cases that correspond to data that appears in the real world) that the error for realistic fixed values of $n$ is actually small.
What you've done in your argument is, without specifying what forms of error we care about in the finite $p$, $n$ model, assumed that taking the limit as $p,n$ go to $\infty$ in the weak convergence topology produces an approximation with acceptably small error. This might be true, but it's certainly not a mathematically rigorous argument step, you have just assumed it. You conclude that the known theory in the case where $p$ is fixed and we take the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ suffices.
The authors instead start from the assumption that the theory from the case where $p$ is fixed and $n$ goes to $\infty$ is applicable only to the case of $p$ small relative to $n$. This might be justified by empirical observations (of failures of previous methods?) or mathematical arguments elsewhere in the paper, but on its own is just as rigorous as your argument since there is no definition of "good enough" for fixed $p,n$ to use. They conclude by the contrapositive that the topology of weak convergence does not suffice to ensure limits of sequences are a good approximation of the members of the sequence and suggest an alternative topology.

Thanks for your reply. Isn't Example 2.6 in http://cermics.enpc.fr/%7Emonneau/Billingsley-2eme-edition.pdf saying exactly that? That we can deduce the $p\rightarrow\infty$ case (with $p =\infty$ understood to mean that we are in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$) from the $p = \text{finite}$ case?

Or are you saying that Example 2.6 suggests an approximation with an error, which is valid for $p$ fixed. However, as $p\rightarrow\infty$ the approximation no longer works as the error term does not vanish to zero fast enough. Hence they suggest a CLT/conditions that ensure fast enough convergence

@Quertiopler Sure, but that's not the point of contention: This is the step that is the same  in both your argument and the paper [1]. The problem is what we can deduce about the case of fixed n and fixed p from the n to infinity limit of the case $p=\infty$ with $p=\infty$ understood to mean that we are in $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$.

@Quertiopler I think what you say is right, but the key point is that in the setting of Example 2.6 we haven't fixed even a definition of what we mean by error. In the paper [1] they immediately after the part you quote consider concrete problems of estimating the distribution of some parameter and one can see for these problems whether weak convergence suffices to study them or not.
